# UIActivityViewController - Remove all Activities starting with com.apple.UIKit.activity.Open.Copy rawValue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to remove all activity types start with `com.apple.UIKit.activity.Open.Copy` from `UIActivityViewController`.

I tried following but didn't get success, anybody does this?

```
func showShareActivity(videoURL : NSURL, onComplete:@escaping (Bool, UIActivityType?, Error?)->()) {
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [videoURL], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.UIKit.activity.Open.Copy.*")]
    activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activity, success, items, error) in
            onComplete(success, activity, erro
       }
    appDelegate?.window.rootViewController?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Note:** When I try to exclude one by one then it works but I want to remove all together (Some of them I may don't know). (Swift/ObjC any solution works.)

`com.apple.UIKit.activity.Open.Copy.com.apple.iMovie`
`com.apple.UIKit.activity.Open.Copy.com.apple.itunesu`
`com.apple.UIKit.activity.Open.Copy.net.whatsapp.WhatsApp`

Basically those are all that starts with `Import with` or `Copy to` text, please refer below image.
[image]

I think Evernote app does the same.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't.